# Customize separator per cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am showing list of items in a `UITableView` in which only the first row will have separator and the rest of the rows won't have any separators. For the rest of the cell I added:

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: cell.bounds.size.width, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

which should remove separators all the rows except first row. But when the app is launched all the cells except the first cell loaded have  partial separators like this:
[image: partial separators on first launch]
on scrolling when the bottom rows are loaded the don't have this issue:
[image: no separators in bottom rest rows]
when I scroll all the first loaded rows out of screen and the scroll back to them all the partial separators are gone:
[image: reloading first-loaded rows removes separators]
I can't seem to find a fix for this issue. Is there any other way I can make the separators disappear by setting their color same as background color?? My xcode version is 11.7 and swift language version 5.

### Update 1

As requested `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` looks like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = countryCodeView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CountryCell") as! CountryCell
        let country = countries[indexPath.row]

        cell.flag.text = country.flag
        cell.countryCode.text = "+\(country.countryCode)"
        cell.countryName.text = country.name
        
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.countryCode.font = UIFont(name: "ProximaNovaA-Bold", size: 16)
            cell.countryName.font = UIFont(name: "ProximaNovaA-Bold", size: 16)
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 16, right: 16)
            cell.tickIcon.isHidden = false
        } else {
            cell.countryCode.font = UIFont(name: "ProximaNovaA-Regular", size: 16)
            cell.countryName.font = UIFont(name: "ProximaNovaA-Regular", size: 16)
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: cell.bounds.size.width, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            cell.tickIcon.isHidden = true
        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: could you provide an executable demo about it? or provide complete code in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Comment: use `.greatestFiniteMagnitude` instead of `cell.bounds.size` your cell bounds is not defined when this code is executed that is why you are having this issue

Comment: Thanks @ReinierMelian, that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `cell.bounds.size` is not correct when this code is executed, so you can use `self.view.bound.size.width` using `UIViewController.view` bounds or directly `.greatestFiniteMagnitude` I prefer use this last one

**Modified Code should be something like this**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = countryCodeView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CountryCell") as! CountryCell
        let country = countries[indexPath.row]

        cell.flag.text = country.flag
        cell.countryCode.text = "+\(country.countryCode)"
        cell.countryName.text = country.name
        
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.countryCode.font = UIFont(name: "ProximaNovaA-Bold", size: 16)
            cell.countryName.font = UIFont(name: "ProximaNovaA-Bold", size: 16)
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 16, right: 16)
            cell.tickIcon.isHidden = false
        } else {
            cell.countryCode.font = UIFont(name: "ProximaNovaA-Regular", size: 16)
            cell.countryName.font = UIFont(name: "ProximaNovaA-Regular", size: 16)
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            cell.tickIcon.isHidden = true
        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

**As alternative you can have an extension for all TableViewCells**

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    func hideSeparator() {
        self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.directionalLayoutMargins = .zero
        }
    }
}
```

**This can be used simply calling this method on cells that you need separator hidden**

```
cell.hideSeparator()
```

Comment: @SoumyaMahunt I personally prefer to use as extension ;) best regards and happy coding

Comment: @Reiner Melian, I am having a new issue where I can see separators for rest of the cells when displayed cells are fewer than the cell that can fit the screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/08nlv.png. Any way around it??

Comment: @SoumyaMahunt you need to set `self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()`on your viewController viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

in the cell class use prepareForReuse() method

put `separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: cell.bounds.size.width, bottom: 0, right: 0)` inside that method. (the default behaviour you expect)

Comment: This produces similar result as before.